# CORS error when creating stripe customer portal session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, stripe-payments

```
  static async stripe_create_customer_portal_session(req, res) {
    try {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({})
          

      const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        return_url: process.env.HOST_URL,
      });

      res.redirect(session.url);
    
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json(error_res());
    }
  }
```

On my React client:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/test_YWNjdF8xTkNuYmRIeW9HSdfssWpMLF9PMXk5dDI5cVlWNjdHbzRnZm1RNThPWXh4VWlheko20100c6j4ViUm' 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:2200/user/stripe/create_customer_portal_session') 
from origin 'http://localhost:2200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /p/session/test_YWNjdF8xTkNuYmRIeW9HS21GdWpMLF9PMXlXSWQ0MVZza1pCOEEydmwzQ1h3UGdrcFhxWXM40100ULtMuOgn). Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I am following the tutorial from:

https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/integrate-customer-portal#redirect

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this problem, you can choose either of the following

- [Frontend] Instead of using XMLHttpRequest , use HTML form POST
  request to create a portal session and redirect. You can refer to
  [here](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/integrate-customer-portal#redirect) for example code
- [Backend] Instead of 303, return 200
  together with the session URL. Process the response in your frontend
  and use JavaScript window.open(sessionUrl)to open the Billing Portal.